# Google Play Developer Console - How do you list your app under the "Live wallpaper" Play Store category?

Tags: android, google-play

In the Google Play Developer's Console, I am trying to set my app's category to "Live Wallpaper", except that category is not listed in the available choices...

This category clearly exists because it is present in the user end Play Store navigation, and it is also mentioned in the developer help centre.

I figure it must be a manifest entry of some sort I forgot to include, or perhaps a in-console setting I missed... Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't Just if your application is LWP (or at least declares it in manifest) it will be listed in this category also. Identical situation like with widgets.

Comment: In that case, a live wallpaper should normally be categorized as Personalization?

Comment: It depands - personalization, or travel, or productivity - I still hope, that this component will finally do "something" more than just consume my battery. Anyway - you should categorize it according the purpose of it not by "it's a wallpaper" exactly this same as you put your apps into some categories based on their functionality nor into "it's an app" category.